# Can start Apache through command line but not through Wamp Server

Tags: apache, wampserver

I have wampserver 3.1.4 running on Windows 10. It starts php & MySql OK but it won't start Apache. 
I can run httpd.exe from the command line and it starts no problem.

The EventViewer tells me I have a Syntax error in my vhosts file on the DocumentRoot line, but I've checked the paths and everything is correct, and it starts OK from the CLI.

Seems to be that wampapache64 has a misconfiguration somewhere.

This is my httpd-vhosts.conf file

The Syntax error occurs on the 'DocumentRoot' line in the second block.
If I remove the second block it works fine.
The path to the folder is correct

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.shiftlegal.co.nz
    DocumentRoot "c:/projects/true/shift/shiftlegal.co.nz"
    <Directory  "c:/projects/true/shift/shiftlegal.co.nz/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I should also note that this exact configuration was working a couple of days ago.

I get 2 error messages in the Windows EventViewer every time I try to run wamp:

```
The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> AH00526: Syntax error on line 16 of C:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.35/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:     .

The Apache service named  reported the following error:
>>> DocumentRoot must be a directory     .
```

Comment: Then please show us your `httpd-vhost.conf` file. Apache does not lie to you just for fun

Comment: Starting WAMPServer launches Apache and MySQL and maybe mariaDB depending on config. It does not start PHP that is running as an Apache module

Comment: Did you install all the MSVC C/C++ runtime libraries before installing WAMPServer? [See the WAMPServer forum](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134915) Look at point 20 These, or at least some of these are required for Apache, the specific MSVC runtime of course depends on which version of Apache you have with your WAMPServer

Comment: Also please show us the Error Message just to give us a bit of a clue

Comment: Have you added `local.shiftlegal.co.nz` to your HOSTS file?

Comment: And please show us the Actual Error Message. Nobody wants to play 20 guesses

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry, edited again. I have added it to the hosts file. Like I said, everything works if I start Apache manually, just not through wamp

Comment: Is that ALL the erro message says, its normally more helpful than that

Comment: That's all I've got. Nothing in the apache_error.log

Comment: Did you install `Visual C ++ Redistributable Packages VC2017 version 14.15.26706` before installing WAMPServer

Comment: Latest one I've got is VC2017 14.12.25810

Comment: The first dialog from the install say clearly that Apache2.4.35 requires `Visual C ++ Redistributable Packages VC2017 version 14.15.26706`

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why we bother with information dialogs. [Download the latest version of MSVC 2017](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads)

Comment: Yeah, except that it was already working before yesterday. Then it stopped. Before I reinstalled it

Comment: Before you reinstalled what?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180843/discussion-between-peter-koopman-and-riggsfolly).

Answer (score 0):

Well.

I'm not exactly sure what happened but it turns out it had not very much to do with wampserver.

It seems my projects folder was corrupted somehow. I created a new folder and added a project and it worked.

Thanks @RiggsFolly for all your help.